# Sequelize include return data format

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a model `User` and the table `userRole` as model `UserRole` has a foreign key `userId` from `User` table.

I have used this query to get the useRole detail of one user:

```
const userFound = await User.findAll({
        where: { userId },
        attributes: { exclude: ["password"] },
        include: {
            model: UserRole,
            as: "userRole",
            require: true,
        },
    })
```

The return value is:

```
[
    {
        "userId": 36,
        "firstName": "a",
        "lastName": "b",
        "userRole": {
            "userId": 36,
            "userRoleId": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "userId": 36,
        "firstName": "a",
        "lastName": "b",
        "userRole": {
            "userId": 36,
            "userRoleId": 5
        }
    }
]
```

How can I make the userRole return as one nested array like:

```
[
    {
        "userId": 36,
        "firstName": "a",
        "lastName": "b",
        "userRole": [
            {
                "userId": 36,
                "userRoleId": 3
            },
            {
                "userId": 36,
                "userRoleId": 5
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

updated:
What I set the relationship is:

```
User.belongsTo(UserRole, { targetKey: "userId", foreignKey: "userId", as: "userRoles" })
UserRole.hasMany(User, { sourceKey: "userId", foreignKey: "userId", as: "users" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have an association like this:

```
User.hasOne(UserRole, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'userRole' });
```

You should replace it with (because one user has many roles):

```
User.hasMany(UserRole, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'userRole' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add associations between User and UserRole before query.

`UserRole.belongsTo(User, { as: 'user', foreignKey: 'userId', targetKey: 'userId' }); User.hasMany(UserRole, { as: 'userRole', foreignKey: 'userId', sourceKey: 'userId' });`

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#one-to-many-relationships